# IntelliJ debug specific stack frame of recursive method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I try to debug a recursive method, I can't step over the recursive method call. Instead, it steps into the method call leaving me with a ton of stack frames when I just wanted to step over that line.

My question is: is there a way to stay within a specific stack frame while debugging a recursive method?

Answer (score 0):

The Step-Over will go line by line and keep separate stack frames for each recursive call , these frames will go away once the return statement is called , you can view each frame separately with its own data in bottom left debugger menu , with each return statement the flow will return and delete these frames but the cursor will always be at the line executed so it won let you in a specific stack frame .

[image: sample recursive debug view]